# How do i find a string within a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, loops, replace, find

I'm working on a Mad-Libs assignment for class.

Essentially I need to isolate a {blank} in a string and print that as a prompt. I then need to return that input to where the blank used to be. This all needs to loop until all remaining blanks are dealt with. I think the replacement is relatively easy, I just need to know how to isolate the {blank}.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that in python,but you could split the line and then recreate a response variable with the user prompt the answer back:

```
a = 'This is a string'
resp = ''
for i in a.split():
   prompStr = prompt_user()
   resp = resp+i+prompStr
```